# mysql insert the information of the current user's into a table

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a table which stores changes made by users to another table

I've got the tables all set up and the if statements, but I don't know the function to store current device, so I would be able to see which pc they used to make the change.

I have the function to store the current users and their id but not their device/computer id, or whatever would be the next best thing?

I have tried looking online but don't seem to find anything?
thank you very much in advance

Comment: I know this is irrelevant, but are you using javascript or java or any other language to store the data into database?

Comment: No i am not, just mysql thanks

Comment: I assume you have already gone through this, if not i hope it may help you.
https://medium.com/@avidyut1/detecting-device-type-from-user-agent-using-mysql-d08133fa8d38

Comment: Are you sure you want to solve this problem directly on database level? Usually, you have some application in front of that database which could handle the processing of user data better

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'TERMINAL' )`

It returns current user's OS ID.

You can read more about this function and it's other parameteres here:
[https://docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions184.htm#SQLRF06117)